# Where is the Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

I thought the Auction House was going down March 18th... I just opened the game after updating to Diablo 3 patch version 2.x and I see no option to open the auction house... Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is they don't have a spot for it on the new UI. It's probably gone a bit early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Auction House button is in the bottom right side of the screen, left of the profile button.